# function and classes getting other data

Tags: php, mysql, function, variables

Ok so i'm trying to get id from user, if I type `$getid = '1'` everything works

```
require_once "../maincore.php";

$getid = '1';
class UploadHandler
{   
    protected $options;
    // ...

    function __construct($options=null, $getid = '1') {

        $this->options = array( 
            'script_url' => 'myfile/'.$getid.'/',

  // ...
```

if i type like `$getid = $userdata['user_id']`
or I put something into class like `$myid = $userdata['user_id'];` and set `$getid = $myid`
then nothing works. I have been trying a lot of stuf and cases for a long time now.
Red tutorials and what are private functions and so on

tried also private `$myid = $userdata['user_id'];` and var `$myid = $userdata['user_id'];`

So I would just like to get data for `$userdata['user_id']` which i cannot manage to get it to work.

Comment: What is `$userdata`? It does not exist in your code …

Comment: what is the output of $userdata, to get output of it write like var_dump($userdata); and let us know the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to pass the data into the class or have the data injected (another topic):

When you construct your class you will tell the class what the values are.

```
//some place in your code
$userdata = array(...some data from somewhere ...);
//$options is optional but at the beginning of the args so the 'null' is required
$class = new UploadHandler(null, $userdata['user_id']);
```

it's often helpful to put *optional* arguments at the end of your function arguments:

```
class UploadHandler
{   
    protected $options;
    // ...

    // Required params first then optional params
    function __construct($getid ,$options=null) {

        $this->options = array( 
            'script_url' => 'myfile/'.$getid.'/',
```

Then you construct your class:

```
//some place in your code
$userdata = array(...some data from somewhere ...);
//$options is now optional and at the end so the default value will be 'null'
$class = new UploadHandler($userdata['user_id']);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as though you're trying to assign a global variable as the default value of a method parameter... This *cannot be done*. There are many reasons for this, but the most important right now is that this contradicts the main idea of OOP: The point of OOP is that you needn't write your code more than once, regardless of what else is going on:

```
class My_DB_Object
{
    private $_connection = null;
    public function __construct($dbType = 'mysql', array $loginParams = array())
    {
        switch(strtolower($dbType))
        {
            case 'mysql':
                return $this->constructMySQL($loginParams);
            case 'pgsql':
                return $this->constructPGSql($loginParams);
            case 'mssql':
                return $this->constructMSSQL($loginParams);
            default:
                throw new InvalidArgumentException($dbType.' is not supported, yet?');
        }
    }
    private function constructMySQL(array $loginParams)
    {
        //and so on...
    }
}
```

This object *could* be used in all of your projects, regardless of what db you're going to use, it might have a `select` method defined, that deals with the different ways to query various DB's, without you having to rewrite the same query's time and time again...

There is no guarantee that the variable you're trying to assign as default value will be set, or will be *in scope*: you might create a new instance inside a member function of another object, that might be in a completely different namespace, too.

Basically: default values are hard-coded. 
A file contains *either* class definitions or code that generates output, your snippet seems to do both.

Your code should look like this:

```
require_once('UploadHandler.php');//or look into __autload()
$uploadInstance = new UploadHandler(null, $userdata['user_id']);
```

Where the `UploadHandler.php` file should look like this:

```
<?php
class UploadHandler
{
    protected $options = null;
    public function __construct (array $options = array(), $getid = '1')
    {//assuming $options should be an array
        $this->options = $options;
        $this->options['script_url'] = 'myfile/'.$getid.'/';
    }
}
//no closing ?> tag!
```